# Store Options Disabled in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Am I doing something wrong here? I have a basic Windows Phone 8.0 SilverLight application and these options are always disabled.

Project > Store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you're referring to is exclusive to Silverlight 8.1 or Windows Runtime (Universal Apps) projects.

Comment: @kyndigs I share your feels